# Why my Joomla gallery link asks for admin access to administrator folder? And how do I fix it?

Tags: joomla, administration

I have an image gallery component, linked to a menu item. I also have my administrator folder secured on my web host (user security). Additionally, my folders are all `CHMOD 755`.

When I click on the gallery link, it pops up the security access form, as if the link or component needs to write to the administrator folder...

Am I overdoing security or is there a permission solution to this issue?

Comment: @Seth 755 sounds fine to me - but you can check your assumption easily by changing the permission to 777 and testing. did you try it ? another thing which is unclear (to me) - are you talking about the administrator control panel or front end access ? also - you can check who's the owner of the folder, you might have to run "chown -R apache:apache <gallery folder>"

Comment: All folders 775.  Trough my CPANEL via my host, I added Folder Security to Administrator folder (CPANEL User password) So if someone access site.com/administrator, it requires authentication. With this enabled, I click on the Gallery link from front-end, and the authentication windows shows up. As if the gallery component needs write permission to the admin folder....
Part of this gallery component allows user uploads, though not enabled. So is the chown what I need to accomplish the issue?

Comment: You can never over do it when security is concerned, more the merrier unless its restricting your audience then you need to have a think.

Answer (score 2):

You should use modules to publish the gallery using:

```
{loadmodule position}
```

With the modules you can restrict who sees the gallery and then within the Gallery manage itself you should have some way of restricting the component to registered/super users. Otherwise opt to use a gallery which is ready out of the box as Joomla has plenty to choose from within the Extension library.